# How to call multiple values from array in while loop in php

Tags: php

> How to add multiple values in while loop, I can only add two values as per my level, one is id and other one is title, I want to add more fields like I am getting from the server please help anyone

```
  $limitStart = $_POST['limitStart'];
    $limitCount = 15;
     if(isset($limitStart) || !empty($limitstart)) {
      $con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
      $query = 'SELECT id, title, caption, description, featured_image, logo, category_sku, industry_sku 
                FROM works ORDER BY title limit '.$limitStart.','.$limitCount .'';
      $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
       $res = array();
       while ($resultSet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $res[$resultSet['id']] = $resultSet['featured_image'];
      }
       echo json_encode($res);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add them all as the `$resultSet` is already an associative array:

```
while ($resultSet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id = $resultSet['id'];
    unset($resultSet['id']); // <-- add this is if you don't want the id in the final set as it's now the key.
    $res[$id] = $resultSet;
}
```

Or to pick an choose certain fields, just do some basic PHP, add the additinonal fields as a new associative array.

Here's an example with adding `caption` and `featured_image`:

```
  while ($resultSet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $res[$resultSet['id']] = ['featured_image'=>$resultSet['featured_image'], 
                              'caption' => $resultSet['caption']];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
$res = array();
while ($resultSet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach($resultSet as $key => $value) {
        $res[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

will do the trick?

Comment: only getting one Id related data, there are other so many id's .

Comment: Could you post a structure of how your data is stored?

Answer (score 0):

If your $limitStart is 14 and your $limitCount is 15 it should return one id.

```
$limitStart = $_POST['limitStart']; // What is this number?
$limitCount = 15;
```

There is a typo in your if statement, see below.

Also your code is vulnerable for SQL-injection because you don't prepare your statements.

```
if( isset( $limitStart ) || !empty( $limitStart ) ) { // Typo here. (small s)

    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $sql = "SELECT id, title, caption, description, featured_image, logo, category_sku, industry_sku 
         FROM works ORDER BY title limit ".$limitStart.",".$limitCount."";

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql); // Prepare the statement
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $limitStart, $limitCount); // Bind the parameters
    $stmt->execute(); // Execute the query

    // Bind the result
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $caption, $description, $featured_image, $logo, $category_sku, $industry_sku);
    $result  = $stmt->get_result();
    $res = array();

    while ($resultSet = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $res[$resultSet['id']] = $id;
    }

    $stmt->close(); // Close the statement
    $mysqli->close();

    echo json_encode($res);

}
```